# DJANGO URLS переадресация эквивалентных адресов

Tags: django, django-urls

Я заметил на многих популярных ресурсах есть такой трюк как переадресация эквивалентных урлов. Например, пользователь переходит на адрес `example.com/abc` ему выдается страница. Затем при переходе по адресу `example.com/abc/` он видит ту же самую страницу и я хочу добиться того же самого. Меня беспокоит строгость `Django` и его слеши в конце, которые не очень красиво смотрятся. Как по мне адрес `example.com/abc` смотрится в разы лучше чем с косой чертой в конце.

Например вот все мои **urls.py**. Как Вы можете заметить в секции `product` нет в конце слеша, потому что `Django` не ругался на меня из-за этого. Но в секции `info` слеши в конце стоят, потому что без слеша `Django` выдает мне ошибку `500`. У меня нет `POST` запросов, только `GET`, поэтому я думаю что могу убрать эти задние слеши. Я искал информацию в Интернете, но все что я смог найти это `APPEND_SLASH` я переопределял его значение на `False`, но ничего не выходило. Так вот как добиться данного результата?

```
app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    # product
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('show/<slug:slug>', views.product_show, name='product_show'),
    path('<slug:category>', views.product_list, name='lst_by_ctgry'),
    path('<slug:category>/<slug:subcategory>', views.product_list, name='lst_by_subctgry'),
    path('<slug:category>/<slug:subcategory>/<slug:kind>', views.product_list, name='lst_by_knds'),
    # info
    path('pad/', views.pad, name='pad'),
    path('guarantee/', views.guarantee, name='guarantee'),
    path('contacts/', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('privacy/', views.privacy, name='privacy')
]
```

Буду рад если просто подскажите в какую сторону гуглить и как это называется. Кто сталкивался с данной проблемой.

Comment: А как по-вашему Django должна догадаться, что ссылка `pad` это на самом деле не `<slug:category>`? Перенесите `<slug:category>` в самый конец, и всё должно стать нормально

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за совет, помогло